# Decomposing isometries in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, isometry

My geometric intuition is a bit weak, and I am trying to understand some basic examples of isometries in the Euclidean plane.

How can you write the following two isometries as a composition of first a function which can be either the reflection across the $x$-axis or the identity map, then a rotation about the origin, and finally a translation?

(i) The reflection across the line $y=3x$.

(2) The translation by $(2,2)$ followed by the reflection across $y=3x$.

I'd really appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, you start with a reflection on the $x$-axis and then you apply a clockwise rotation of $2\arctan(3)$ radians around the origin. Then you apply the null translation.

For the second one, start with a reflection on the $x$-axis and then you apply a clockwise rotation of $\arccos\left(-\frac45\right)$ radians around the origin. Then you apply the translation by $\left(-\frac25,\frac{14}5\right)$.

Comment: How did you get the number $2\arctan(3)$? And for the second one, are you accounting for the reflection across $y=3x$?

Comment: It was chosen so that each point of the line $y=3x $ is mapped into itself.

Comment: I still don't see how you get your answers. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 The slope of the line $y=3x$ is $3$. After reflecting it on the $x$-axis, ye get the line $y=-3x$, whose slope is $-3$. The way of mapping this line back to the line $y=3x$ through a clockwise rotation around $(0,0)$ is by choosing a rotation of $2\arctan(3)$ radians.

Comment: I see, but for the second isometry I mention, isn't your decomposition the same as a translation by $(2,2)$? How do you include the reflection across $y=3x$ that follows it?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 I misunderstood your second isometry and shall edit my answer.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Please do the math. The reflection on the $x$-axis is the map $(x,y)\mapsto(x,-y)$. The matrix of the rotation that I mentioned is $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}-4/5&-3/5\\3/5&-4/5\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$.